# Error: Command '['dot', '-V']' returned non-zero exit status -5 When using Iris

Tags: python, python-2.7, netcdf, grib, python-iris

After I installed the package `Iris` with `conda install -c scitools iris`,

Whether using Ipython console or Jupyter notebook, the `iris` was always failed to import. The error subroutine shows like:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-005053b25f37> in <module>()
----> 1 import iris

/Users/TEST/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/iris/__init__.pyc in <module>()
    110 import iris.cube
    111 import iris._constraints
--> 112 import iris.fileformats
    113 import iris.io
    114 

/Users/TEST/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/iris/fileformats/__init__.py in <module>()
     23 from six.moves import (filter, input, map, range, zip)  # noqa
     24 
---> 25 from iris.io.format_picker import (FileExtension, FormatAgent,
     26                                    FormatSpecification, MagicNumber,
     27                                    UriProtocol, LeadingLine)

/Users/TEST/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/iris/io/__init__.py in <module>()
     31 
     32 import iris.fileformats
---> 33 import iris.fileformats.dot
     34 import iris.cube
     35 import iris.exceptions

/Users/TEST/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/iris/fileformats/dot.py in <module>()
     41             # Check PATH
     42             subprocess.check_output([_DOT_EXECUTABLE_PATH, '-V'],
---> 43                                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
     44         except OSError:
     45             _DOT_EXECUTABLE_PATH = None

/Users/TEST/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in check_output(*popenargs, **kwargs)
    571         if cmd is None:
    572             cmd = popenargs[0]
--> 573         raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
    574     return output
    575 

CalledProcessError: Command '['dot', '-V']' returned non-zero exit status -5
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error - almost:  CalledProcessError: Command '['dot', '-Tsvg']' returned non-zero exit status 1 when using scikit tree classifier in Jupyter. pip and conda installed Graphviz. !dot -V returns dot - graphviz version 2.38.0 (20140413.2041)

Answer (score 2):

I raised a similar issue on the iris GitHub tracker (https://github.com/SciTools/iris/issues/1899). Essentially, as much as I believe it was intended to be optional, the way it has been implemented I think Iris actually requires a `dot` installation. With conda, that should look like:

```
conda install graphviz
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already installed the `graphviz 2.38`. And the problem still remain.

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case, this error was resolved by [installing GraphViz](https://www.graphviz.org/download/).

I believe the root case of this issue is that the `graphiz` python bindings cannot find the command line utilities required to render the output into some form, e.g. `.pdf`, `.svg` or `.png`.